# Subclassing a class, while needing to use the delegate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Say for example you want to subclass `UIScrollView` to create `UITableView`, and you don't want to use any private interfaces.

In order to load cells, you must use the the parent's delegate (`scrollViewDidScroll` in `UIScrollViewDelegate`). Additionaly, you want to add some of your own methods to the delegate (e.g. `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`).

What I do now is:

1. Create `UITableViewDelegate` protocol which extends `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol.
2. Create `UITableViewDelegateProxy`, which I set as `super.delegate`, in `UITableView`'s `init`.

   This class conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate` and has a `next` property, which *may* reference an object conforming to `UITableViewDelegate`.

   By default, it tries to respond using it's own implementation. If that isn't available, it tries with the `next`'s implementations, otherwise it doesn't respond.

   ```
   - (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
   {
       if ([super respondsToSelector:aSelector])
           return YES;
       else if (self.next)
           return [self.next respondsToSelector:aSelector];
       else
           return NO;
   }

   - (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation
   {
       // self did not respond to selector
       if (self.next)
           [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self.next];
       else
           [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:anInvocation.selector];
   }
   ```

   So up to now, this class is totally transparent and future-proof if `UIScrollViewDelegate` is extended.

   Then I add implementations for some of the delegate methods to change the default behavior or add some more behavior (e.g. call `next`'s `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` in `scrollViewDidScroll`).
3. Override `delegate` and `setDelegate:` in `UITableView` to return and set `super.delegate.next` instead of `super.delegate`. I also change the protocol from `UIScrollViewDelegate` to `UITableViewDelegate`.

This works OK if `UIScrollView` is accessing the delegate via it's ivar directly. If it uses the getter, it will not return our proxy, but instead the delegate set by the user of the class. Either way, we can't rely on this behavior. (fyi: In `UIScrollView`, it goes through the getter sometimes, but not always).

So if we stay with this example, the question is: **how could we implement UITableView, *exactly as it is today*, ourselves?**

Comment: See this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11478740/shared-uitableviewdelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it and preserve the contract, which is unfortunate. It's somewhat unusual that `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`; on the desktop Cocoa side of things, `NSTableView` does not inherit from `NSScrollView`.