# Shared UITableViewDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I'm writting a subclass of UITableView and I want my subclass to handle some of the UITableViewDelegate methods itself before passing them along to the "real" delegate as well as forward all the UITableViewDelegate methods not implemented by my subclass.

In the subclass I have a private property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <UITableViewDelegate> trueDelegate;
```

which holds the "real delegate" that all the unimplemented methods should forward to. In both my init methods I set

```
self.delegate = self;
```

and I override - (void)setDelegate:(id) like this

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id<UITableViewDelegate>)delegate {
    if (delegate != self) {
        _trueDelegate = delegate;
    } else {
        [super setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

Then I override these to handle the message forwarding

```
-(NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    NSMethodSignature *sig;
    sig = [[self.delegate class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:aSelector];
    if (sig == nil) {
        sig = [NSMethodSignature signatureWithObjCTypes:"@^v^c"];
    }
    return sig;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {
    SEL selector = anInvocation.selector;
    if ([self respondsToSelector:selector]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:self];
    } else {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:_trueDelegate];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the unimplemented delegate methods never get called on the tableview, therefore they are not given a chance to be forwarded along to the _trueDelegate object.

I tried checking for them here:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {

}
```

but that method is never called for the UITableViewDelegate methods although it catches other methods just fine.

Comment: Did you declare your extended class as conforming to the delegate protocols?

Comment: I ask 'cause it's possible that the tableView uses `conformsToProtocol:` instead of `respondsToSelector:` when calling delegate methods.

Comment: Indeed I did, that very well could be the problem, I'll check that out

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For performance, `UITableView` checks and remembers which delegate methods are available as soon as the delegate is set. You set the delegate `self` first, then the `trueDelegate`. So at the time the delegate is set on the `UITableView`, `trueDelegate` is `nil`, and so `-respondsToSelector:` on that one always returns `NO`.

To fix that, set the delegate after `trueDelegate` is set. Also, you can simplify the forwarding code. Remove all the code you have above except for the property and replace it with:

```
- (void)setDelegate:(id <UITableViewDelegate>)delegate
{
    if (delegate == self) return;

    self.trueDelegate = delegate;
    [super setDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    if ([super respondsToSelector:aSelector]) return YES;

    return [self.trueDelegate respondsToSelector:aSelector];
}

- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector
{
    return self.trueDelegate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect, just curious, how did you know about the UITableView optimization mentioned?

Comment: I stumbled over it some time ago when looking into implementing delegates the right way. The `_tableFlags` in `UITableView.h` give a pretty good hint that `UITableView` caches which methods are implemented in its delegate/data source.

Comment: Awesome answer, tried everything until got your hint.

Comment: @NikitaIvaniushchenko Glad that I could help!

Comment: @TammoFreese do you know if there is any documentation or further write up to the fact table views 'cache' function responses?

Comment: @markturnip I don't know of any official documentation on UITableView caching which selectors its delegate responds to. There is only one other mention I could find in a response to an issue reported for ReactiveCocoa in 2014.